# What is the DC component of a Fourier Series?

Tags: fourier-series

So I used the following Fourier Series equation to compute the Fourier Series of a square wave with period 2pi and goes from -1 to +1.

[image]

I computed the a0 term to equal zero and just containing the odd sinusoidal terms in the series. This is what is also online so I know I computed the series for the square wave properly. But I was confused by what it is the DC component of a Fourier Series like in a square wave? Is it the a0 term?

To include a DC component for a square wave, would I just shift the Fourier series upwards by setting the a0 term to a nonzero value?

Comment: Correct. Alternatively, you can view $a_0$ as the average value of the signal over the domain of periodicity. By comparison, each of the harmonics in $g_{T_0}(t)$ correspond to AC components of various frequency.